# How do I create an Azure Function App v4 using Azure Resource Manager API

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager

Consider the following code that worked for function apps prior to `v4`:

```
var bindingsConfig = new
{
    bindings = new object[]
        {
            new
            {
                AuthLevel = "function",
                Type = "httpTrigger",
                Direction = "in",
                Name = "request",
                Methods = new[] {"post"}
            },
            new
            {
                Type = "http",
                Direction = "out",
                Name = "$return"
            }
        }
};

app = await myResourceGroup.GetWebSites().GetAsync("my-app-name", ct);
var func = await app.GetSiteFunctions().CreateOrUpdateAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, "my-func-name", new FunctionEnvelopeData
{
    Config = BinaryData.FromObjectAsJson(config)
}, ct);
```

Now according to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=javascript%2Cwindows%2Cazure-cli&pivots=nodejs-model-v4), `function.json` is no longer used in `v4` programming model. My question is - does it mean I shouldn't be passing `bindingsConfig` into `CreateOrUpdateAsync()`? When I try it though I get the following error:

```
Azure.RequestFailedException: 'Error creating function. <my-func-name> is not a valid function name
Status: 400 (Bad Request)
ErrorCode: BadRequest
```

In general how should I call `CreateOrUpdateAsync()` to create a `v4` kind of function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested in resolution, it turns out that the call to `app.GetSiteFunctions().CreateOrUpdateAsync()` should never be used for creating function v4. This call results in creation of the v3 style of `function.json` which gets in conflict with the v4 programming model (v3 and v4 programming models shouldn't be mixed in one app).

It is also important to make sure you call `npm install` if the `node_modules` folder is missing (in Kudu UI).